# Mobile application development in .Net?

Tags: android, ios, windows, visual-studio, mobile

I am new in developing Mobile application.

Can anyone please gimme some info regarding how to develop a mobile application ( Android, iOS, Windows) using Visual studio?

If so, in which Edition of visual studio is that possible to develop a cross platform ( Android, iOS, Windows) .

I am using Visual studio 2013 Express Edition. I have tried using Xamarin , but I want using Visual studio.

Please share some info .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Poor `Visual studio` fan. If you want to develop native app and want to use a single IDE then your whole life will be spent on resolving issues created by your IDE. If you're developing cross platform app then still I will suggest you to use eclipse for that. It's free and has lots of add-ons.

Comment: and by the way, the only cross-platform solution which is nearest to the native apps seems to be the Qt - http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/developing-with-qt.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Xamarin add-on for Visual Studio? You don't have to use the Xamarin SDK, there is an extension that you can add to Visual Studio here --> http://xamarin.com/visual-studio and I'm sure it will work with Visual Studio 2013 Express Edition.

You can have a look at these alternatives http://alternativeto.net/software/xamarin-studio/

Comment: I have tried using Xamarin , is that the only software? any other idea??

Comment: I have edited my answer with a site listing alternatives. Please mark as an anwser if this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

For windows phone you can use  Mobile development SDK. After downloading Mobile development SDK you have to install it. After installation you can create mobile application(windows) using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to develop so easily for all different platforms just in Visual Studio, you will need to look at some Cross platform alternatives:

- PhoneGap
- Titanium
- Xamarin

Its not a quick fix solution I am afraid, you are better off learning one native framework at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio 2013 Express Edition then you can not extend it, so you will not able to use xamarin plugin.you need to use Xamarin Studio for this.If you are able to get Visual studio Business Edition then you can get this done simply adding plugin.

[Also check this studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio plugins are NOT available for any express edition.
You compulsorily need a non-express edition of Visual Studio for installing the xamarin plug in.

In order to get the plug in you need to get the $999 per year per developer business plan. 
mentioned here. https://store.xamarin.com/ .
For windows phone 8 anyways you use VS.
for android you get this plug in from xamarin. Even for IOs you get theplug in but, you need a mac for debugging running apps on the ios simulator which is not yet seen on windows. So you need pairing your PC with a Mac for ios.
Cheers.